# Circular motion and Car's Tire Angle

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to figure out what angle to turn the front tires of my small robotic car (about a foot in length) so that it moves in a circle (on level ground) of radius $r$ (will be accommodating circles of different radii). In addition to being able to set my car's speed, it is equipped with a sensor which includes a gyroscope, accelerometer, and a magnetometer.

I'm just looking for some kind of equation that relates the car's tire angle, the car's speed, the circle's radius, and maybe the angular velocity readings from the gyroscope.

It has a car-like configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering Stackexchange. Which [configuration](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Robotics/Types_of_Robots/Wheeled#2-by-2_powered_wheels_for_tank-like_movement) does your robot have? Car-like with the two front wheels steerable and the rear wheels fixed?

Comment: See [steering geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry)

Answer (score 3):

As a beginning, it is highly encouraged to start by [Ackerman's angle theory](https://sweetmfg.biz/uploads/files/tech-04understandingsteering-4.pdf) which models street car turning theory.

You should define more your robot configuration, and decide which variables are dependent on each others and which not.